# Запятая между «что» и «когда»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> По опыту я твёрдо знал, что(**?**) когда белая ослепительная яркость
> поглотит всё пространство, я заново открою глаза и наступит утро.
> [Михаил Елизаров. Мультики](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dAtZ1SZE4KoC&pg=PT208&lpg=PT208&dq=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%83%20%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=-n_JxkyU9j&sig=ACfU3U3-cgRLbJrYARhI-SVAFDLIlSzPog&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj82vj-utX1AhVNEncKHUtJCJcQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%83%20%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

Запятой у автора нет. Это ошибка?

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, *КирКа*. На будущее, для сведения: в цитате точка ставится после закрывающих кавычек; если же Вы оформляете в вопросе предложение знаком цитирования (вертикальной полосой) , то кавычки, собственно, и не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это ошибка, поскольку отсутствует коррелят *"то"* (или подобный).

Правило:

> ...при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза
> и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй
> придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически —
> если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза *то*, *так* или *но*,
> наличие которой требует такой перестройки)... (Розенталь "Пунктуация", § 36).